# fancyvrb + listings inside a list

Tags: listings, lists, fancyvrb

I'm trying to put `Verbatim` environment from `fancyvrb` package, with
activated interface to `listings` package, inside `enumerate` environment.

When `Verbatim` environment is first element in `\item`, item's label is
mysteriously moved to left margin. For `lstlisting` and `Verbatim` without
`listings` interface, everything works as expected.

**Is this a bug in `listings` interface to `fancyvrb`, or am I somehow misusing those packages?**

I'm using newest versions of both packages: `fancyvrb` 2.8, `listings` 1.5e.

## Minimal working example

[image: labels moved to left margin]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\noindent
Reference text.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting first line
lstlisting second line
    \end{lstlisting}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
        \begin{lstlisting}
lstlisting first line
lstlisting second line
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim first line
Verbatim second line
    \end{Verbatim}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
        \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim first line
Verbatim second line
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\lstset{fancyvrb}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim + listings first line
Verbatim + listings second line
    \end{Verbatim}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
        \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim + listings first line
Verbatim + listings second line
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

## Workaround

I think I have a workaround for my problem, involving adding `\hskip` to `\@labels` box inside `Verbatim` environment. **I'd like to know whether there
are some potential dangers associated with it and does anyone have a better solution.**

[image: labels fixed]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{fancyvrb=false}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\MyFixVerbatimLabels%
  {%
    \lst@iffancyvrb%
      \setbox\@labels\hbox{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \unhbox\@labels}%
    \fi%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent
Reference text.

\fvset{formatcom=\MyFixVerbatimLabels}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim first line
Verbatim second line
    \end{Verbatim}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
        \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim first line
Verbatim second line
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\lstset{fancyvrb}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim + listings first line
Verbatim + listings second line
    \end{Verbatim}
  \item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item
        \begin{Verbatim}
Verbatim + listings first line
Verbatim + listings second line
        \end{Verbatim}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've sent a bug report to `listings` maintainer.

Comment: Any news here? Did you get any response?

Comment: @TeXnician I wrote an email to address given in listings manual, but got no response. Problem is still present in listings 1.6.